# TFS 2017 - Retrieve Trigger information build definitions

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Im trying to retrieve the schedule of the vNext BuildDefinitions through my C# Application.

I can retrieve the BuildDefinition objects that i need.

```
List<BuildDefinitionReference> builddefs = buildClient.GetDefinitionsAsync().Result;
```

and

```
var buildDef = buildClient.GetFullDefinitionsAsync(project: project,
name: buildDefName).Result.ToArray();
```

But when looking at the BuildDefinition.Trigger information, this does not seem to contain what i need.
Simular to the XAML builds, i want to be able to read the BuildDefinition.Schedules, to see when each build is scheduled.

Who knows where this information is currently kept ?

Update:
Fixed the issue by converting the BuildTrigger to a ScheduleTrigger

```
if (buildDefinition.Triggers != null)
{
    foreach (BuildTrigger trigger in buildDefinition.Triggers)
    {
        if (trigger is ScheduleTrigger)
        {
            ScheduleTrigger scheduleTrigger = trigger as ScheduleTrigger;

            foreach (var schedule in scheduleTrigger.Schedules)
            {
                //Do magic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package to the latest version and the **GetFullDefinitionsAsync** method should return the schedules information, that are stored in **Triggers** property instead of Schedules property.

Comment: Thanks i got that far, when debugging the code i see the information i am looking for, but the BuildTrigger object through the API only contains the DefinitionTriggerType, nothing else.How can i best code it so that i can access the information ? should i debug, lookup the names and loop over the values later trying to find the info i need ?

Comment: @Nico You need to convert the result type to `ScheduleTrigger`, for example: `ScheduleTrigger st = currentDef.Triggers.First() as ScheduleTrigger;`

Comment: Thanks Starian, i knew it must have been something like that. Im not sure if multiple instances of the ScheduleTrigger can exist, so i loop over the BuildTriggers, i posted the solution in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Rest API to [Get a build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-build-definition), a sample:

```
GET https://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/build/definitions/29?api-version=2.0
```

Then you will get a response as below which include trigger information:

```
  "triggers": [
    {
      "schedules": [
        {
          "branchFilters": [
            "+$/MyFirstProject/Test"
          ],
          "timeZoneId": "UTC",
          "startHours": 3,
          "startMinutes": 0,
          "daysToBuild": "all",
          "scheduleJobId": "18316444-edbb-479d-950d-7714ba39d3d6",
          "scheduleOnlyWithChanges": true
        }
      ],
      "triggerType": "schedule"
    }
```

And the each member for your reference:

> **Members**
>
> **branchFilters:** string[].
>
> **daysToBuild:** [ScheduleDays](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/scheduledays). Days for a build (flags enum for days of the week)
>
> **scheduleJobId:** string. The Job ID of the Scheduled job that will queue the scheduled build. Since a single trigger can have multiple
>   schedules and we want a single job to process a single schedule (since
>   each schedule has a list of branches to build), the schedule itself
>   needs to define the Job Id. This value will be filled in when a
>   definition is added or updated. The UI does not provide it or use it.
>
> **startHours:** number. Local timezone hour to start
>
> **startMinutes:** number. Local timezone minute to start
>
> **timeZoneId:** string. Time zone of the build schedule (string representation of the time zone id)

Details please refer [Schedule](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/schedule) Rest API.